# Mixpanel Initialize Error: argument passed to call that takes no arguments

Tags: swift, xcode, mixpanel

I have a very simple question, with hopefully a very simple solution.

Mixpanel's official documentation says to initialize in 'didFinishLaunchingWithOptions' with:

```
Mixpanel.initialize(token: "MIXPANEL_TOKEN")
```

When I put it in there with my token, I get this error: "Argument passed to call that takes no arguments"

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    Mixpanel.initialize(token: "MIXPANEL_TOKEN")
```

This was working just fine a couple months ago, but now it's not. How can I fix this and why is this not working?! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Will from Mixpanel's Support Engineering team. Happy to point you on the right track with this.

To dive in, what integration method did you use to implement our [Swift SDK](https://github.com/mixpanel/mixpanel-swift) in your app? If you used CocoaPods can you confirm that you've updated to the latest version of CocoaPods? To update you should be able to execute `sudo gem install cocoapods` to update to the latest CocoaPods version. Once that's complete, can you try updating your pods by running `pod update` in the directory of your Xcode project to ensure that you're on the latest version of our Swift SDK. We'll also want to make sure you're not selecting the prompt to convert legacy Swift code to Swift 3 (if shown).

If going through those steps doesn't resolve it would you mind writing into support@mixpanel.com? A member of our Support Engineering team can take a look at your implementation and get things sorted!

--Will

Comment: Hey Will. Thanks for the response. I updated CocoaPods as you suggested. I am using the Pod Install method and importing into xcode.

I checked and looks like it's running Mixpanel 3.1.3. Really not sure where the error is coming from as this worked just fine not that long ago.

Comment: Figured it out. Looks like you guys might have changed it to Pod 'Mixpanel-swift'. I believe before we were using Pod 'Mixpanel', so I was using that instead. It works great now after changing!